# WPF Why the assigned background cannot override setter value in style triggers?

Tags: wpf, triggers, styles

I have a `Style` for a `TextBox` like this:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBox_Standard" TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}" >
    <Setter Property="Control.FontFamily" Value="/#Calibri" />
    <Setter Property="Control.FontSize" Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="Control.Margin" Value="2" />
    <Setter Property="Control.Height" Value="21" />
    <Setter Property="Control.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="UndoLimit" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
            <Border 
              Name="Border"
              CornerRadius="1" 
              Padding="1"
              Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
              BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}"
              BorderThickness="1" >
              <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Arrow"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Arrow"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

It was made to make sure the foreground color to be black and background color to be gray when it's not editable.

but apparently now there's a requirement to change the background programmatically when it's not editable, so I tried it like this:

`txtBox.Background = Brushes.Yellow;`

but what happens is it still have a white background when editable and gray background when not editable.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try with this

```
   <Style x:Key="TextBox_Standard" TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}" >
        <Setter Property="Control.FontFamily" Value="/#Calibri" />
        <Setter Property="Control.FontSize" Value="12" />
        <Setter Property="Control.Margin" Value="2" />
        <Setter Property="Control.Height" Value="21" />
        <Setter Property="Control.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="UndoLimit" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                    <Border  
          Name="Border" 
          CornerRadius="1"  
          Padding="1" 
          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
          BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}" 
          BorderThickness="1" >
                        <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Arrow"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Arrow"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: i see it's working when it's in editable mode, unfortunately i actually need it to be yellow when not editable 

note: i did it by creating new style, i just wanna know if i can do it by modifying the current style i have so it can be used for both cases:
(1) textbox A -> editable - white, non editable - gray, (2)
textbox B -> editable - programmatically, non editable - programmatically

Comment: No, You won't be able to use the same style in both the cases, as you are using triggers they will be excuted whenever IsReadonly or IsEnabled property values changes. You can create a new style to be used in B, without any triggers and inherit style for A from that one.

Comment: ahh, so it can't be done eh T_T

well i'll just create a new style for it then

thanks guys